# No provider for angular service error

Tags: angular2-services

I have created an angular 2 service and a component.
Component is registered in the NgModule and the in the providers of NgModule the Service is registered. 
But when I am injecting the same service in the constructor, I am getting runtime error saying No provider for ***Service.
Why is this happening? Anybody has the solution?

Comment: Show your app.module and component code where you add service in constructor.

Comment: Please find the code for app.module and component here https://gist.github.com/shahu725/c4528f75a431a673101364c936c5f4bf

Comment: Thank you @PiyushPatel ! The issue was with the file path not with constructor. In visual studio I just dragged and dropped the .ts file for service and it taken the path in all small case. But one of the folder name was in the capital case because of which the component was unable to detect the service.